# Boost XML parser can support <![CDATA[ … ]]>?

Tags: xml, boost, cdata, boost-propertytree

I had able to read the XML file using boost and writing the same content to another file .

```
<data>
<![CDATA[This is Test]]>
<prod name= "p1"/>
</data>
```

while writing to another file this would changes to below format.

```
<data>
This is Test
<prod name= "p1"/>
</data>
```

Here unformatted texts like Is missing in the output file.

can some one help on how to write the exact as format for unformatted texts like ?

Answer (score 0):

Boost does **not** have an XML parser.

Boost Property Tree /uses/ an XML parser to... implement property tree persistence.

The XML parser it uses under the hood is a version of RapidXML.

RapidXML does support CDATA: [RapidXML giving empty CDATA nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029167/rapidxml-giving-empty-cdata-nodes/21030387#21030387)

I doubt Property Tree uses it.